# Intellij ask ssh password for each project push/pull

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh, gitblit

I use git plugin for IntelliJ for the project versionning.

Since yesterday, each time I push a file or pull a project, IntelliJ ask for my password for each file.
I think that I missclick somewhere and change the configuration of my IntelliJ/Project but I don't know what.

[image]

How can I get rid of this message and enter my password only once like I did till yesterday ?

I already generate a public ssh key in my ~/.ssh/ folder and I enter it in my GitBlit profile.